# Disable address validation for PayPal Express Checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, paypal-express

I'm using Magento 1.9 and have PayPal express checkout enabled.

And I have the problem that when a user makes a typo on his shipping address and tries to pay with PayPal it will receive the following error:

> PayPal gateway has rejected request. A match of the Shipping Address
>   City, State, and Postal Code failed

I know that this is due PayPal validating the shipping address on its end, but I was wondering if there is a way to **completely disable this** on Magento. I have read on several sources that the way to fix this is by editing:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php
```

And removing this line:

```
$request['ADDROVERRIDE'] = 1;
```

But I have done so already but I keep getting the same message.

Is there anything else I could try?

Thanks.

Comment: did you found solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried changing `address_override` to 0 rather than removing it?

I'd shy away from editing that file directly as it'll be kicked out if you upgrade magento. Better to create a copy of that file in `/app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php` and modify that.

(thanks to https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/26102 for that)